# how to create a list of list of objects from a list of objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So, I am trying to create a list of list of objects using some existing data. The data i have contains 2 values i.e. 'a' and 'b' with many similar values of 'a' recurring many times in the dataset.

What i am trying to do is to convert the data in such a format that for any value of 'a', the list would contain all the value of 'b' corresponding to its 'a' value in a single place.

The Dataset is :

```
const tempData = [
{a: 1557637200025, b: "aaaa"},
{a: 1557637200025, b: "bbbb"},
{a: 1557637200025, b: "cccc"},
{a: 1557637200025, b: "dddd"},
{a: 1557637200025, b: "eeee"},
{a: 1557637200025, b: "ffff"},
{a: 1557637200025, b: "gggg"},
{a: 1555563600017, b: "hhhh"},
{a: 1555563600017, b: "iiii"},
{a: 1555563600017, b: "jjjj"},
{a: 1555563600017, b: "kkkk"},
{a: 1555563600017, b: "llll"},
{a: 1555563600017, b: "mmmm"},
{a: 1555563600017, b: "nnnn"},
{a: 1555563600017, b: "oooo"},
{a: 1555563600017, b: "pppp"},
{a: 1555563600017, b: "qqqq"},
{a: 1555563600017, b: "rrrr"},
{a: 1555563600017, b: "ssss"},
{a: 1555563600017, b: "tttt"},
{a: 1555563600017, b: "uuuu"},
{a: 1557982800028, b: "vvvv"},
]
```

And i want it to look like this:

```
const newTempData = [
{
 a: 1557637200025,b: [
    "aaaa",
    "bbbb",
    ...
]},
{
 a: 1555563600017,b: [
    "hhhh",
    "iiii",
]},
...

]
```

I have tried basic `nested for` loops and i am getting no where close to achieve what i am seeking.I am not getting any way to update the row1 value inside for loop for row2, so that i can stop the loop to match the values again and again.

```
        var newTempData =[];
        for(let row1 in tempData){
            console.log(row1);
            var some =[];
            var row2 = Number(row1)+1;
            var x = tempData[row1].a;
            for(row2 in tempData) {
                var y = tempData[row2].a;
                var instance = tempData[row2].b;
                if( x === y ){
                    some.push({ ins : instance});
                }
            }
            newTempData.push({a: x,b: some});
        }

        console.log(newTempData);
```

The output i am getting is this.

```
0: {a: 1557637200025, b: Array(7)}
1: {a: 1557637200025, b: Array(7)}
2: {a: 1557637200025, b: Array(7)}
3: {a: 1557637200025, b: Array(7)}
4: {a: 1557637200025, b: Array(7)}
5: {a: 1557637200025, b: Array(7)}
6: {a: 1557637200025, b: Array(7)}
7: {a: 1555563600017, b: Array(14)}
8: {a: 1555563600017, b: Array(14)}
9: {a: 1555563600017, b: Array(14)}
10: {a: 1555563600017, b: Array(14)}
11: {a: 1555563600017, b: Array(14)}
12: {a: 1555563600017, b: Array(14)}
13: {a: 1555563600017, b: Array(14)}
14: {a: 1555563600017, b: Array(14)}
15: {a: 1555563600017, b: Array(14)}
16: {a: 1555563600017, b: Array(14)}
17: {a: 1555563600017, b: Array(14)}
18: {a: 1555563600017, b: Array(14)}
19: {a: 1555563600017, b: Array(14)}
20: {a: 1555563600017, b: Array(14)}
21: {a: 1557982800028, b: Array(1)}
```

I just want to get the desired data without repetition. Right now i am able to get the data but it is repeating for every matched value of 'a'. I want to know better ways to do it rather than my amateur way. Thanks.

Comment: The desired output isn’t actually a valid JS object, e.g. the value of `b` is an array of `{"aaa"}`. Can you update you question with valid output?

Comment: Oh yeah, @MasonStewart. Just edited it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). I have commented out the check if `b` is already in the array, depends if you want repeated `b` values or not.

```
const tempData = [
    { a: 1557637200025, b: "aaaa" },
    { a: 1557637200025, b: "bbbb" },
    { a: 1557637200025, b: "cccc" },
    { a: 1557637200025, b: "dddd" },
    { a: 1557637200025, b: "eeee" },
    { a: 1557637200025, b: "ffff" },
    { a: 1557637200025, b: "gggg" },
    { a: 1555563600017, b: "hhhh" },
    { a: 1555563600017, b: "iiii" },
    { a: 1555563600017, b: "jjjj" },
    { a: 1555563600017, b: "kkkk" },
    { a: 1555563600017, b: "llll" },
    { a: 1555563600017, b: "mmmm" },
    { a: 1555563600017, b: "nnnn" },
    { a: 1555563600017, b: "oooo" },
    { a: 1555563600017, b: "pppp" },
    { a: 1555563600017, b: "qqqq" },
    { a: 1555563600017, b: "rrrr" },
    { a: 1555563600017, b: "ssss" },
    { a: 1555563600017, b: "tttt" },
    { a: 1555563600017, b: "uuuu" },
    { a: 1557982800028, b: "vvvv" }
];

const result = tempData.reduce((acc, { a, b }) => {
    const element = acc.find(el => el.a === a);

    // If element exists
    if (element /* && !element.b.includes(b) */) {
        element.b.push(b);

        return acc;
    }/* else if ( element ) { return acc; } */

    acc.push({ a, b: [b] });

    return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: Yeah repeated values of b is ok. TYSM. I have to learn a lot. This sorted my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about performance, instead of using `.find()` of your array, you could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) :

```
  function add(map, {a,b}) {
    if (!map.has(a)) {
      map.set(a, {a:a, b:[]});
    }
    map.get(a).b.push(b);
    return map;
  }

  const result = Array.from(tempData.reduce(add, new Map()).values());
```

EDIT: or even better, use an object as in @Vishal Sharma's answer, has less overhead than a map.

Comment: Thanks, Actually my dataset is quite huge and i think it will be best if i use better performance practices.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running `.find` each time you could create an object `{}` as part of reduce, to avoid the effort of finding the element each time, and later use `Object.values`

```
const result = Object.values(tempData.reduce((acc, {a, b}) => {
    if (acc[a]) {
        acc[a].b.push(b)
    } else {
        acc[a] = {a, b: [b]}
    }

    return acc
}, {}))
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal. It was very helpful and i got to learn a few new things from this.